# win phone 7 + XMPP + phonegap

Tags: windows-phone-7

Thanks for editing but i am talking about XMPP server not XAMPP server.

I can't connect to XMPP server using win phone 7. It gives error,

```
"message":"Access is denied.\r\n",
"description":"Access is denied.\r\n","number":-2147024891}
```

xmpp server is on linux

Comment: Please post the code used to connect to XAMPP server

Comment: var msg = "<body rid='"+this.rid+"' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' to='"+domain+"' xml:lang='en' wait='"+this.wait+"' inactivity='"+this.inactivity+"' hold='1' content='text/xml; charset=utf-8' xmpp:version='1.0' xmlns:xmpp='urn:xmpp:xbosh'></body>";
   console.log("url :"+this.url);
   console.log("sended msg :"+msg);
   
   console.log("at ajax");   
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
        url: this.url,
        data: msg,
                    success: function(data){
     console.log("Cdata ::" + data);
                },
                   });   
  },